# Couch DB Design

Tags: couchdb

I'm currently looking to design a new couch DB, and need some advise on the most effient method/way of laying , setting it up.

The DB will be local and will consist of a single DB, with my multi docs looking like,

```
{"name":"bob","age":"32":"data":"........."}
{"name":"fred","age":"33":"data":"........."}
{"name":"jane","age":"34":"data":"........."}
 .... few thousand more documents !
```

The thing will be the data value will consist of a few thousand lines. 
As there will be a few thousand documents, what will be the best way to say show me the doc that contains name "fred".
Or will this type of look up no create any performance issues ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I guess `name` isn't unique hence not appropriate at all for `_id` so you can then make a view that returns `name` as a `key`. Then you can query that view for all `keys` matching "fred" and then lookup the documents of interest using the returned `_id`s, or perhaps use `include_docs`.